# Options to Delete Entity child from children when deleted in parent object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, blazor, entity

I have the following classes

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    publict int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

In the blazor frontend the parent object is changed and some children are deleted.
first get parent include childs:

- Parent.where(id==id).include(children); (kind of)

then delete & update childs in edit form

- Parent.Children.remove(id==id)

submit form and send Parent object to db for storage:

After:

```
ctx.update(parent);
ctx.savechanges();
```

The children are updated but the deleted children are still in the DB.
Is the only option to remove the deleted children,
to get the existing children from the DB where parentId == ParentId and compare them with the updated children?

Comment: maybe you can add more details, can you show the code before you call the savechanges?

Comment: Yes, its an edit function to delete one or more childs or update them in the list. The object is Parent with children list, the expected values are in the new parent object.

Comment: so you want to remove all the Children? sorry I'm just trying to understand so I can answer you properly

Comment: Im sorry, no.. I just want to remove only the children in de DB from the object parent, which are removed in the frontend. I dont know if the above edited expaination is more clear? Like parent = GetParent.include.children. In the frontend parent.childlist.remove(id==0) & parent.childlist.remove(id==12). The updated parent object is send to the db for storage. But child with id 12 & 0 are still in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try using

```
ICollection<Child> Children
```

instead of using

```
IEnumerable<Child> Children
```

then try to remove the child object(debug to validate) from the parent object, then call ctx.Update(parent) method(I assume this is not tracked)

Example:

```
@page "/"
@inject ParentChildContext context
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<button @onclick="@(() => DeleteChild())">Click me</button>
@code {
    Parent parent;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            parent = new Parent()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Parent 1",
                Children = new List<Child>() {
                new Child() { Id = 1, Name = "ChildName" },
                new Child() { Id = 2, Name = "ChildName2" }
            }

            };
            context.Parents.Add(parent);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

    }

    private async void DeleteChild()
    {
        parent.Children.Remove(parent.Children.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1));        
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed the IEnumerable to ICollection. In the udated parent object the child is deleted. After calling update the deleted child is still in the DB. Or do you mean make a extra call to DB to delete childs that are connected with the parent but not in the Edited Parent object child Collection?